# Add a cell only if certain conditions are met

Tags: swift, uitableview

So i have an array of struct where i add data from my json. There are different types of data in the same array.

```
struct PersonData {
    let name: String
    let age: String
    let sex : String
}
```

What i want to do is to implement a pickerView that will reload the table view depending on what the user choose. Lets say i have 2 picker views where the user can choose sex and age.

So if he chose all males with 17 years old i want to show only that on the table view.

I can already get the count on the array but i can't return nil on the `UITableViewCell` method

I wanted to do something like this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseCell", for: indexPath) as! CellTeatroTableViewCell

        if(option == 0) //All persons. Default option
        {
            cell.name.text = dataArray[indexPath.row].name
            return cell

        }
        else
        {
            if(dataArray[indexPath.row].age == agePickerOption || dataArray[indexPath.row].sex == sexPickerOption )
            {
                cell.name.text = dataArray[indexPath.row].name
                return cell
            }
        }

        return nil

    }
```

I know i cant return nil since he is expecting a UITableViewCell but its possible to only increment the indexPath if certain conditions are met?

Or i need to add the cell and delete it right after? This doesn't sounds right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have two data arrays:

**allDataArray** - all elements

**filteredDataArray** - elements that comply to your filter

If you use the **filteredArray** as a DataSource you dont have to put that logic in the cellForRow Method.

Instead, use the picker delegate methods to filter your **allDataArray** and put it on the **filteredDataArray**.

Comment: Damn how did i miss that? Such a simple solution. I dont know how could i miss using one array as the data source. Thanks a lot Lopes!

Comment: No problem ;) Good Coding